# Are the aliens in the Hey Duggee episode 'The Space Badge' real, or imagined?

Tags: hey-duggee

In *Hey Duggee* season 2, episode 28 "The Space Badge", Duggee is using his telescope to stargaze.

The Squirrels play with cardboard and create a space rocket, they then have an imaginary journey through space.

At the episode end, after the Squirrels have left with  their parents, Duggee is standing outside the hut beside the play rocket. For a second there are 2 or 3 aliens suddenly visible from behind the rocket.

My question: Were these aliens a continuation of the imaginary space journey earlier in the episode, or was Duggee having a close encounter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the space aliens were *fictional creations of the children*, it stands to reason that the aliens depicted at the end of the episode were still part of the fantastical voyage.

> **Narrator:** *Nobody's sure if there is anyone else in space, Betty.*
>
> **Tag:** *But what about aliens? Little green aliens?*
>
> **Betty:** *Or big purple ones?*
>
> **Happy:** *Or little cute ones?*
>
> **Roly:** *Or **invisible** ones?*
>
> **Narrator:** *Well, space goes on and on. How far? Nobody knows. So there could be other creatures out there, somewhere.*

Comment: Obviously the next question is "***who's the narrator and how is he able to speak to the children?"***

Comment: @DannyMcG - I'm aware of the voice actor. The question is who he is *in-universe*